# Doctrine (Symfony) very slow select with many left join

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-query

Doctrine very long time (126.04 ms) makes a query and returns data if query contains select with many (6) LEFT JOIN and returned many data (more when 1200 rows)

My query:

https://gist.github.com/Neokortex/218463a50f57529d6e0caf9b82fc4aa9

A week ago I did not notice this. Why does this happen?

UPDATE: indexes do not help.

The server is very powerful

Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E3-1230 v5 @ 3.40GHz, 8 cores

32 GB Memory

I CRY :(

Comment: Do you really want all the columns listed in select clause ? I advice you to just add the required columns only not all from your 6 tables, Also what about indexes ?

Comment: You're probably missing indexes on your tables.

Comment: ^ That. 1200 rows and 6 joins isn't that much, shouldn't take that time.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the query is executed and returned data long enough, even if I do not select all the data

Comment: @JasonRoman if execute the query through the mysql command line, it runs very quickly. can this mean that the indexes will help me?

Comment: I'm not sure. You should try running an EXPLAIN query. Also 126 ms isn't a super long time, especially if Doctrine is creating an object with 6 associations.

Comment: indexes do not help